System design- constructing sequence diagram using MVC pattern
I am currently modeling a social media application using the MVC design pattern and intend to construct a sequence diagram to illustrate the process flow. The use case I am focusing on involves the creation of a post. Here are the sequential steps involved:

The user clicks on the ‘Create post’ button.
The system presents a modal for the user to create a new post.
The authenticated user enters the content they want to post.
The system displays an alert notification confirming the action.


Is this sequence diagram correct?

Why is the image a link, and not embedded in the question?

@MarkSeemann because i need 10 reputations to post an image

Ah, sorry, I didn't realize that.

Is this on-topic for SO?  It doesn't seem like it, this seems better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/  It's not really a programming problem.

And where is the Model from your diagram? :)

@PeterCsala the model is the post class , there's no need to show other models as they aren't invloved

The diagram is almost correct from the UML perspective...
This diagram is correct, in the sense that:

it corresponds to the described sequence, except that there are some more elements,
the syntax is ok, except that the message names and stereotypes should be above the arrow and not hide/interrupt it, and the «create» message should be dashed and open-headed.

Some details need to be cross-checked for consistency and disambiguation. Only you can do this:

There is no 'Create post button'. This is not a problem since the diagram suggests an equivalent behaviour.
The open-headed arrows are asynchronous messages.  Going by the book, there should be no reply message but another normal message in opposite direction. (However, this is a very strict interpretation and many modelers use a reply message as you did).
On one side you interrupt the activation (black rectangle) after store() and on the other you continue the activation after createPostContent(). I'd suggest to continue both, or interrupt both, unless there's a justification that yiu use a different approach.
Do you really mean that you create a new database every time you want to post?  Or is it rather a database connection that you create, and the database stays persistently ?
Conversely,  do you really mean to have a modal windows and just activate it when needed ?  or don't you create such a window every time you create a new post ? (there's no right or wrong here, it depends on your underlying UI API).

... the diagram is however  wrong from the MVC perspective
In the original MVC, the user sends commands and input to a controller (or a sub-controller responsible for a specific view) and receive notifications from a view. The view could query the model to display it.  But could also be notified by the model in case of change.  So the sequence would look like (simplified):
User -> Controller -> Create/activate view
User -> WindowController -> Post -> View -> User  

In MVC, the model would be responsible for interacting with the database. The database is not necessarily needed in the diagram: If you introduce it,  the challenge is that there a are different architectures that can be considered for the interaction between the model and the database, from the active record (what you did here,  the post being responsible to interact with the database) to a mode complex but powerful repository, through the table data gateway and many other valid approaches.

Thank you for your response. I made some mistakes in the modalView by forgetting to connect the activation. Additionally, I should have updated the naming of the createpostoption for the create post button. Regarding the reply message, I included the alert notification as a reply because I've been taught that they are optional, but I'll remove the other reply messages as they might not be necessary. As for the database, I planned to create a new connection, but I can remove this if needed.

And Also regrading this "the user sends commands and input to a controller" I've followed a book that shows the sequencing I did. actor -> view -> controller ->model

@tjn Thanks for this opportunity to clarify: my point on the reply is only for the asynchronous messages (open arrow head). What I meant is that the notification should then be a normal (synchronous or asynchronous message). For all the other (synchronous) messages, you can perfectly leave the reply: they contribute to a good understanding of your diagram, even if they are optional.  If you want to highlight that sometimes there is a notification, and sometimes there isn't, you could use a normal message in an opt combined fragment.

@tjn regarding the book, the interactions in the classic MVC model are well established but often misunderstood. So there are plenty of variants. I provided a link to the original description by the MVC inventor. The Main problem is that many frameworks associate the MVC controller (the code that manages input from the user and translate it into commands for the view or the model) to the window. This is why some people (like your book author) think that the window's controller is part of the view. When users interact directly with the view, it's MVVM and not MVC.

@tjn here some mor infos about the differences. But let's not start a pattern war. If your intent is to model MVC according to the book, and the book proceeds as you have described, there is no issue and you can disregard the second part of my answer (I leave it posted for other readers who could be puzzled if they follow the real MVC pattern)

Thank you for your guidance, @Christophe. I appreciate your responses. However, I have a slight concern. Could you please provide an example of how the sequence diagram is supposed to look? Also, I'm curious if the windowController remains fixed for all use cases, as I've defined operations for all interactions. Alternatively, will I need to use a different controller based on the use case?

@tjn usually you'd have a main controller at application level,  and use several windows controller (because most UI frameworks work like this).  But whether you show one controller (because in the end you consider that the windows controller is  just a part of the larger controller) or two in the diagram,  is a matter of how detailed you want your diagram to be.  In MVC, the controller is about UI.  If you start to think of controllers per use-case, you might glide into ECB (entity control boundary) pattern, where the controller has a business logic role beyond the MVC controller.

so for each UI page im gonna have a window controller?

if needed, yes!
